# Is std::chrono::system_clock::now always successful?

Tags: c++, std, c++-chrono

In this cppreference 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now, std::chrono::system_clock::now is **noexcept** function, and the **Return value** section doesn't told me it will failed.

So can I assume that std::chrono::system_clock::now is always successful?

Comment: it can't fail, like you said

Comment: In what case would you expect it to fail?

Comment: @DavidHaim is there a document to prove it?

Comment: As documented, it won't fail. But of course, the C++ standard is an ideal. On some computers, the hardware time could fail

Comment: Read some C++ standard specification, e.g. [n3337](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n3337.pdf) to find out. But a C++ standard is not the complete reality of an implementation, just an agreed-upon ideal

Comment: Your machine always knows what time is it. the time might be incorrect, but this is not a function. if the function is marked "noexcept" and the return value is always valid the function can't fail

Comment: @Wonter what should this document say? "This function really, really, really won't fail. We swear!"

Comment: I'm really not sure how such a function could fail. All it has to do is read a permanent OS resource that  must be there for the computer to even operate. And perhaps do a little math on it.

Comment: It is easy for a library developer to make it fail if the hardware has no RTC.  He simply returns the same number for every call.  A successful failure.